# Ansible path resolution in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible, pipeline

I've wrote a simple playbook because I wanted to automate config deployment to some of my VMs:

```
---

- hosts: monitoring
  become: true
  roles:
    - monitoring
```

The `roles/monitoring/tasks` file

```
- name: Deploy Dashboards
  ansible.builtin.import_tasks:
    file: deploy-prometheus-alerts.yml
```

and task file

```
---

- name: Copy Prometheus alerts configuration
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ azdo_workspace }}/monitoring/config/"
    dest: "/opt/buka2/prometheus/config/"
    mode: '0644'
    group: 'domain users'
    remote_src: yes
```

then the `azure-pipeline.yml`

```
steps:
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: SshKey
    displayName: "Download ssh private key"
    inputs:
      secureFile: "test.id.priv"

  - bash:  |
      ansible-playbook -v -i ./inventories/test/hosts.yml main.yml \
        --user testserviceuser \
        --key-file "$(SshKey.secureFilePath)" \
        -e "ansible_become_pass=$(ansible.test.pass)" \
        -e "azdo_workspace=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
    displayName: test copy file
    workingDirectory: ansible
    # Probably should be a better way
    # https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/connection_details.html#managing-host-key-checking
    env:
      ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: False
```

ansible fails with the error:

```
fatal: [BUILD-AGENT]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source /__w/1238/s/monitoring/config/ not found"}
```

the `pwd` from ansible point of view is wird when i did `ansible.builtin.shell: pwd`

```
"/home/svcazdevopstest@corp.itsroot.biz"
```

and the `hostname` is already indicating my remote, however the `src` parameter of [ansible.builtin.copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) says *"Local path to a file to copy to the remote server."* which i would expect in my case to be build agents working directory.

So I would really appreciate if someone could explain how this all should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's important to use correctly the `remote_src: yes` param. In my case I was looking for files in wrong host.